# Sprockets::FileNotFound for jquery-rails on a basic install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sprockets

jQuery cannot be found for some strange reason. I'm on a (basically stock) install of **Rails 5.1.1**

I'm using the `jquery-rails` gem, which *is* installed properly, so jQuery should be readily available in the assets pipeline.

**Gemfile** (gems global and NOT in :development or :test):

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

**Error**

> Sprockets ::FileNotFound
>
> couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'

This is about as basic of a setup you can get. What could be going on?

I've run `bundle show jquery-rails`, `bundle update`, and `bundle install` multiple times. Everything looks fine.

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, countless times. I ended up just physically placing jquery in the assets pipeline for now until I can determine what is going on

Comment: Good solution for that, good luck, you can also try in Rails 4 may be it is an issue with Rails 5 only